# Variable Javascript Arguments / Parameters

Tags: javascript

In the example function below, there are three arguments that will be used for sure and a variable amount of additional arguments that are at least one.  What this means is that the function will always have at least four arguments (active, count, index, businessOne, .., ..).

With this in mind, how do I make my function accept a variable amount of arguments?

```
var updateCommercial = function(active, count, index) {

if (active) {

  slideContent.splice(0, count);

  active = false;

} else {

  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {


    var arrayIndex = index + i;


    slideContent.splice(0, arrayIndex, businessOne, businessTwo, businessThree);

  }

  active = true;

}
```

}

Comment: aren't you already doing it with `for (var i = 3; i < arguments.length; i++) {` ?

Comment: Your `for(... arguments.length...)` looks correct already

Comment: Your function already accepts a variable amount of arguments. The problem lies within how you access them. You use `arguments` object and access the argument by its index, example: `arguments[0]; arguments[1];` etc. However, do note that `arguments` is not an array, it is only *similar* to an array. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).